# Select for indexed field with >= is much faster than with =

Tags: mysql, index, performance, query-performance

Execution time for the query

```
SELECT id
FROM Deals
WHERE is_demo = 0 
AND asset_id >= 71 
AND exp_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(UTC_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL 30 HOUR);
```

is 0.5s, but if we change `asset_id>=71` to `asset_id=71` the execution time is about 10 seconds.

Why `>=71` if much faster than simple equal operation `=71`?

Indexes for all fields are used.

```
CREATE TABLE `Deals`
(
    id INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    is_demo TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    asset_id INT(11) NOT NULL,
    exp_time INT(11) NOT NULL,
);
CREATE INDEX asset_idx ON `Deal` (asset_id);
CREATE INDEX exp_timex ON `Deal` (exp_time);
CREATE INDEX is_demo ON `Deal` (is_demo);
CREATE INDEX user_idx ON `Deal` (user_id);
```

Comment: Any particular reason you don't use composite indexes? How do you determine that "indexes for all fields are used"?

Comment: Do this please, `OPTIMIZE TABLE Deals` (If may be long. Don't run on prod), then provide the execution plan for both queries, i.e. run `EXPLAIN the query`

Answer (score 2):

With `>=`, the optimizer had two indexes to choose from.  Apparently it chose `(exp_time)`.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to confirm this. Also run `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`

With `=`, the optimizer still has two to choose from, but probably picked `=` `(asset_id)`. But there were a lot of 71's, so it turned out to be a bad choice.

That choice can be improved by having `INDEX(asset_id, exp_time)` in place of simply `(asset_id)`.  This may run faster than even 0.5s.  This 'composite' index can use both parts of the `WHERE` clause, thereby being more efficient.  (The `>=` version can't use both columns of a composite index because it can't handle 2 ranges at the same time.)

And even better than  `(asset_id, exp_time)`: `(is_demo, asset_id, exp_time)` or `(asset_id, is_demo, exp_time)`.

It could be that the "statistics" are stale -- run `ANALYZE TABLE Deals` to see if things improve.  But don't hold your breath; this is not a panacea.